# Can mongodb find's lt operator take the document field as argument

Tags: mongodb

I have a document which looks something like this

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("5bcef414b4305f4054571305"),
   "timestamp":   ISODate("2018-10-23T10:12:36.755   Z"),
   "config" : {
       "expiry_duration" : NumberLong(10000)
    }
}
```

I need to find documents which are expired ,i.e, whose `$datediff(time.Now(), $timestamp)` > `config.expiry_duration`

I am not clear if I need to use aggregate or if I can achieve this using find itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `.find()` method but you need [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) operator (which is available in MongoDB 3.6):

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
        $gt: [ { $subtract: [ ISODate("2018-10-23T16:39:06.266Z"), "$timestamp" ] }, "$config.expiry_duration" ]
    }
})
```

To get current date you can type `new Date()` in Mongo shell

If you need a solution for MongoDB < 3.6 you can use `.aggregate()` and [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/index.html) pipeline stage:

```
db.col.aggregate({
    $redact: {
        $cond: {
            if: {  $gt: [ { $subtract: [ ISODate("2018-10-23T16:39:06.266Z"), "$timestamp" ] }, "$config.expiry_duration" ] },
            then: "$$KEEP",
            else: "$$DESCEND"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks @mickl  the expr was the missing piece. I was surprised why all my search results were leading to aggregate when this is a pure find function.